# Is it possible to change the user's shell system-wide without using chsh?

Tags: macos, command-line

Using `chsh` in Catalina is annoying because during a system update `/etc/shells` is reverted back to the default content. I use Fish as my shell and I don't want to keep an eye on that file. Is there a way to set the default shell system-wide (so I don't have to touch my terminal emulator preferences) for a given user without using `chsh`? Something like Linux's `usermod` would be nice

Comment: What do you mean system wide? Chsh just changes the current user's shell

Comment: Probably `system-wide` is not the right term, sorry. I'm looking for a way to tell all the apps that my user runs which is my shell

Comment: What do you think `usermod` does, that `chsh` does not?  Also, why do you think an update will replace `/etc/shells`?  I've had `/usr/local/bin/ksh` in mine for ages, Catalina just whines with a entry in Relocated Items but doesn't replace the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish USERNAME
```

to change user `USERNAME` to a shell which isn't listed in `/etc/shells`.

PS: Might be worthwhile to create a second admin account first so you won't get locked out if the behaviour changes with future releases.

Comment: OK, apparently I was misled, now I'm reading the manual (sorry!), and looks like you can use any shell, even one that's not listed in `/etc/shell`, as long as you are an administrator? Does it depend on some group?

Comment: @Tae As an administrator (or with `sudo`) you can *change* the shell for *any* user, independent of whether that user is an administrator itself.

Comment: I understand that. What confuses me is when the shell should be listed in `/etc/shells`? I thought it should be there always, but apparently that's not the case?

Comment: @Tae What we know for sure is that a binary needs to be listed in `/etc/shells` to allow non-admin users to use `chsh` for it. Also login via `ftp` will not work if the user shell is not listed there (maybe other logins will fail as well).

Comment: Thanks for all your patience, it works as described